# How to query data by month and year using EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using this code for getting the data by month and year but it's not the right result. See the code

```
var result = uow.CompliedInspectionRepository.All
    .Where(c => c.IsCompleted == false || c.IsCompleted == null
                && (c.DueDate.Value.Month == i && c.DueDate.Value.Year == year));
```

any suggestion or how to do it in EF?

Comment: Please give some examples: Situation, what you're expecting, what you get.

Comment: Looks like you need more parentheses here. Try `c => (IsCompleted == false || IsCompleted == null) && (...)`

Comment: "*But it's not the right result*"...what result did you get? What were you expecting?

Comment: i have a list of data that has due dates, i need to get the data by duedate month and duedate year. thanks

Comment: What is the type of DueDate?

Comment: duedate data type is datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might have the brackets in the wrong place

```
c.IsCompleted == false || c.IsCompleted == null && (c.DueDate.Value.Month == i && c.DueDate.Value.Year == year)
```

I think this will return results 
where (iscompleted is false or iscompleted is null)
and( month and year match)

you could try

```
(c.IsCompleted == false) || (c.IsCompleted == null && c.DueDate.Value.Month == i && c.DueDate.Value.Year == year)
```

where iscomplete is false or 
( iscomplete is null and month and year match)